# Why doesn't this declarative net request rule work?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to block a website with a chrome extension that uses the new declarative net request API for Manifest V3, but it isn't working at all. I have added the permission in the manifest and made sure to add the priority, id, action and conditions, but it still doesn't do anything at all. Since I am blocking only one domain, I tried changing the domain list in the conditions from "domains" to "domain" but this just blocks every domain. Here is the applicable part of my manifest. I'm not sure why, but when I open the website in a private/incognito tab, occasionally, it will work.

```
"declarative_net_request" : {
    "rule_resources" : [{
      "id": "rules1",
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "rules.json"
    }]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest"
  ],
```

Here is my rules.json file.

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "block"
    },
    "condition": {
      "domains": ["google.com"],
      "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
    }
}]
```

Comment: Replace `"domains": ["google.com"]` with `"urlFilter": "||google.com/"`

Comment: Wow, surprisingly that worked, how come this works but "domains" doesn't? The thing is though, trying this for YouTube, this doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Trying it in incognito for youtube, it works. If you're not in incognito then it doesn't work on YouTube. I've tried clearing browsing history, cache and cookies, but it still has this issue. Any idea why?

Comment: 1) `domains` does a different thing, it's for requests made by this site(s) when they're already opened. 2) Try unregistering youtube's service worker in devtools -> Application and if it helps, use chrome.browsingData.remove to do it in your extension's onInstalled listener.

Comment: I just had a similar issue but different cause. [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps) uses Service Worker to cache its requests and `declarative_net_request` wouldn't touch them. Only solution is to clear the data but it's very hard to explain to users how or why.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the "Domains" tag to "requestDomains" or "initiatorDomains" since the "Domains" tag is deprecated. I am assuming that the google.com is your initiator Domain which means you want to block all requests originating **from** google.com to any destination website. If you want to block google.com from being a destination website i.e you want to stop any requests being made **to** google.com, you need to use the "urlFilter" tag instead.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, google does a terrible job at telling us what's deprecated. domains was deprecated and we have to use initiatorDomains instead:

what worked for me was:
inside your rules conditions -

urlFilter: "https://example.com" to block a request **going to** your "https://example.com"
and then:
initiatorDomains:["mail.google.com"] to block a request ***coming from*** "mail.google.com" (just an example)

must include in the manifest version 3
"host_permissions": [ "<all_urls>" ]

if I had that example on how to block from and to, it'd have saved me a lot of time. I hope this helps